# All looks good but no data being returned

Tags: square-connect

I'm testing Square API - the PHP API to send credit card info via the 'Payments Form'.

The goal is to enter CC information to the form and try to make a payment for $100. Then I want to see the amount via the user control panel where payments are listed.

I created a developer account, added the credentials: location id, application id, access token. The nonce is created and the process-card.php code is run.

However what am I supposed to see? All I get back is a blank screen. The response variable/array should contain something but it is empty. Where is the data being sent? How do I see my payment? I go over to my location dashboard and no payments are being recorded.

When I test with the sandbox I get a bunch of return data - where would I go to see that payment being received?

Any help would be gratefully received.

Thanks all.

Answer (score 0):

If you are seeing something different with the sandbox vs your production credentials, You are likely getting an error that you aren't seeing/isn't being properly displayed.

First, I'd make sure your account can process payments by calling the locations endpoint and seeing the capabilities of your location. You should see something like

```
"capabilities": ["CREDIT_CARD_PROCESSING"],
```

If you don't try visiting [squareup.com/activate](http://squareup.com/activate). If that doesn't seem like your issue, Make sure you check the javascript console of your page, and that you can see the error and warning logging of your PHP script.

To see the transactions from your sandbox credentials, you only need to call [ListTransactions](https://docs.connect.squareup.com/api/connect/v2#endpoint-listtransactions) with those same sandbox credentials.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for the reply.

Ok I figured it out.

I didn't finish the sign up process and account info details for my Square account. I finished the sign up process.

Then I went to the test form and filled in my real credit card credentials. The form sent a payment of $1 which I was now able to see in the dashboard. All seems to be working well. I received data back from the API and can continue building out the application.